# Help with steps in proof of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality, vector-spaces

I don't grasp some steps in this quick proof of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

> Let $\boldsymbol{u}$ and $\boldsymbol{v}$ be two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality states that
>   $$
> \boldsymbol{u} \cdot \boldsymbol{v} \leq |\boldsymbol{u}||\boldsymbol{v}|
> $$
>
> We know that 
>   \begin{align}
> |\boldsymbol{u}+\boldsymbol{v}|^2&=(\boldsymbol{u}+\boldsymbol{v})\cdot (\boldsymbol{u}+\boldsymbol{v})\\
> &=
> \boldsymbol{u}\cdot \boldsymbol{u}+\boldsymbol{v} \cdot \boldsymbol{v} +2\boldsymbol{u}\cdot \boldsymbol{v}\\
> &=|\boldsymbol{u}|^2+|\boldsymbol{v}|^2+2\boldsymbol{u}\cdot \boldsymbol{v} \tag{1}
> \end{align}
>   Using Cauchy-Schwarz, we have 
>   $$
> |\boldsymbol{u}|^2 +|\boldsymbol{v}|^2+2\boldsymbol{u}\cdot \boldsymbol{v} \leq
> |\boldsymbol{u}|^2+|\boldsymbol{v}|^2+2|\boldsymbol{u}||\boldsymbol{v}|=(|\boldsymbol{u}|+|\boldsymbol{v}|)^2 \tag{2}
> $$
>   So the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives
>   $$
> |\boldsymbol{u}+\boldsymbol{v}|^2 \leq (|\boldsymbol{u}|+|\boldsymbol{v}|)^2 
> $$
>   or 
>   $$
> |\boldsymbol{u}+\boldsymbol{v}| \leq (|\boldsymbol{u}|+|\boldsymbol{v}|)
> $$

I don't understand the inequality in equation (2). How can we conclude the inequality? I.e why is 
$$
|\boldsymbol{u}|^2 +|\boldsymbol{v}|^2+2\boldsymbol{u}\cdot \boldsymbol{v} \leq
|\boldsymbol{u}|^2+|\boldsymbol{v}|^2+2|\boldsymbol{u}||\boldsymbol{u}| \quad\text{?}
$$

And how is $\boldsymbol{u} \cdot \boldsymbol{v} \leq |\boldsymbol{u}||\boldsymbol{v}|$ equivalent to $
|\boldsymbol{u}+\boldsymbol{v}| \leq (|\boldsymbol{u}|+|\boldsymbol{v}|)$?

Comment: This is not a proof of the inequality, it is a proof that uses it.

Comment: Remember that $u.v$ is the product of the norm and the cosinus of the angle (which is bounded by $1$).

Comment: see here i hope this will help you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality

Answer (score 3):

This is a proof of the triangle inequality $|u+v| \leqslant |u| + |v|$ that depends on the truth of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $u \cdot v \leqslant |u| |v|$. This proof is not proving the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, it is using the validity of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in order to prove something else.